# GDB Debugging Multithreading, Execution is Unpredictable for Single Thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, gdb

I'm new to GDB and not sure if any of you have experienced: When I used GDB to debug a program that has 2 threads, I found the execution of stepping line by line is not linear or it's unpredictable even for one single thread and the variable value printed out is also confusing. Say I have a program(in C++) looks like this:

(I'm debugging on ubuntu commandline, using the `-tui` mode of gdb).

```
.....
    70 for (int i = 0; i < MAX; i++) {
    71     int foo = 1;
b+  72     Bar *bar = f1();
    73     int v1 = bar->doCalc();
    74     int v2 = bar->get(foo);
    75  }
.....
```

In the beginning, the program stopped at the `line 72`, then I stepped line by line until it reaches `line 74`. At this moment, I printed out the value `v1`, but it seems this variable still doesn't have meaningful value yet. Then if I type "next", the program execution jumps back to `line 72` again!! This is the first thing caused my confusion. Then I continue step to next line, until it reaches `line 74`. At this moment, I printed out `v1` and this time it has some meaningful value. I double checked the iterator `i`, its value are the same, that means it's in the same i-th execution of one loop. I'm confused, how can this happen? Could somebody help me out? Thank you!

Comment: You haev all compiler optimization turned of, yes?

Comment: When debugging multithreaded apps, it's often better to continually set breakpoints at the next line rather than attempting to single-step. Single-stepping often results in the 'next step' moving to unrelated code as the code you were following makes a syscall.  Of course, if you have multiple threads running the same code, it's even more confusing - a single-step command sometimes makes it seem like the code is running backwards:)

Comment: This seems very little unrelated to multiple threads, and all related to compiler optimizations. For starters `foo` doesn't actually need to be a variable; `i` may be optimized out entirely (or may be updated only every <n> iterations due to unrolling). Variable assignments don't need to be in order; `v1` and `v2` don't actually need to exist or be assigned at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The symptoms you described match what is *expected* when debugging optimized code. Make sure you compile without `-O2` or similar flags, or add `-O0` to the end of your compile commands.

Multi-threading is unlikely to have anything to do with your problem (although it does present its own challenges when single-stepping). *IF* multithreading is affecting your debugging, you should see messages in GDB, such as `[Switching to Thread 0x7ffff61ec700 (LWP 21427)]`, when execution switches from one thread to another.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is because the code has been optimized when compiling. I used `CMake` to generate the Makefile. And I used the `RelWithDebInfo` flag for compiler, which according to what I've found means: _ompiler flags for compiling a release build with debug flags from C sources_. So I guess it's still more or less optimized for execution. Then I changed the flag to `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`, it works like a charm now.